# Is there a way to get the data from the player_list?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

For example on hypixel, I would like to get the formatted names like `[VIP] Person [GUILD]`. It has to come from the player list, external sources will not work for my circumstances.

I've tried getting the displayName or username of a `NetworkPlayerInfo`, but that was to no avail. I am new to forge modding and I have searched a lot for solutions but there just isn't a lot of resources out there. Since I'm developing for 1.8.9, I can not ask for help on the forge forums. Thanks for any help